# Reading a section of data from one sheet and applying conditional formatting to equivalent entries on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a one sheet of data sorted by date, where A2:X45 are one year, then below A47:X92 are the next year, etc. Months are by column from A3:X3. A2 and A46 are where the year is labeled. A1 is a merged cell from A:X with the title of the spreadsheet. Every other column (B, D, etc) is for what day the data was recorded.

In another sheet are columns of each data type and the data that falls under that type in each those columns. The second sheet then counts the amount of data of that type and displays the sum. At the moment, after inputting new data in the first sheet I have to change the color of the cell manually, then input the new data into the second sheet corresponding to its type.

I'd like to be able to input new data into the first sheet, then the second sheet according to its type (types are qualitative so would be unable to automate that part), and have a formula or conditional formatting check the first sheet for the exact same text. If there are exact text matches, then the cell(s) that match on the first sheet would change to the color of the data type. I'd also need to specify a certain range for the formula, as equivalent data from one year will have a different type the next year.

If there are any further questions please ask, I understand this description is vague but I can't delve too deep into the specifics of the data. Solutions are welcome in Excel or Google Sheets.

Edit: Included below are mockups as requested to give a better idea of what I'm describing. Was not able to post images directly due to lack of reputation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T47y3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb4pg.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a mock up and desired output.  You do not need to share real data but a simplified mock up will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Do you want to get the result based on the background color?

Comment: @Lee Yes, based on the background color of the types on sheet 2. A watermelon in 2021 in the blue column of sheet 2 should be blue on sheet 1, and a watermelon in 2022 in the yellow column of sheet 2 should be yellow on sheet 1.